# read from socket and write into file C++

Tags: c++, sockets, fstream

Im looking for some working and efficient way of writing data, recieved by socket, into file.
Right now im doing this:

```
if (!fStream.is_open()){
    cerr << "Unable to open file stream.\n";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
char* recBuffer = new char [MAX_SIZE];

bzero(recBuffer, MAX_SIZE);
ssize_t recieved;
while ((recieved=read(s, recBuffer, MAX_SIZE))>0){
    fStream.write(recBuffer,MAX_SIZE);
    bzero(recBuffer, MAX_SIZE);
}
```

Problem of this implementation is ... lets say im recieving text file, when i write recieved data into file, file contains recieved data + NULLs from rest of the memory. If i write only recieved count, i see only NULLs in file.

p.s Boost::Asio is not an answer for me :(.

Thanks

Comment: You do know that streams are buffered? If the buffer have not been flushed nothing will actually have been written to the file. You may want to flush the buffers after each write just for testing. And the `bzero` calls are not needed if you remember to write only `recieved` bytes.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
fStream.write(recBuffer,MAX_SIZE);
```

should be

```
fStream.write(recBuffer,received);
```

And do not need the `bzero` bit on both lines

Comment: as i 've written i write only recieved count, i see only NULLs in file. Maybe i have bug on server side then ...

Comment: You probably have exactly the same bug on the server side.